# How to pass the data path for object flash tag from the root directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm using [urlrewriting](http://www.urlrewriting.net) to rewrite my url. Let me introduce my problem by bellow example:
Here is old url: http://localhost/test/pages.aspx?pageid=1
I have 2 cases to rewrite:

1. http://localhost/test/url-rewriting-get-start.aspx
2. http://localhost/test/url-rewriting/get-start.aspx

The first case is ok, but I would like to use the second case. In this case I must use root path for image, css and object tag (for flash):

- With image, I modified to: `<image src="~/images/icon.jpg" runat="server"/>`
- With css, I modified in head tag: `<head runat="server">`
- But with the object tag, I don't know how to set root for the data, movie parameter:

  `<object data="anim/head.swf?xmlPath=./menu_flash.html" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="962" height="228">
  <param name="movie" value="anim/head.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />`

Anyone have solution for this, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Tien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use root path in param tag?

```
<param name="movie" value="/[path starting from root]/anim/head.swf" />
```

Alternatively, you can use server tags to resolve path such as

```
<param name="movie" value='<%= this.ResolveUrl("/[path starting from root]/anim/head.swf") ' />
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. This statement help me alot

Answer (score 0):

If the flash movie is in the root folder of your website, you could write the tags as either:

```
<object data="/anim/head.swf?xmlPath=./menu_flash.html" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="962" height="228">
<param name="movie" value="/anim/head.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
```

OR

```
<object data="http://localhost/anim/head.swf?xmlPath=./menu_flash.html" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="962" height="228">
<param name="movie" value="http://localhost/anim/head.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
```

Hope this helps!